# What is the code for this sentence?

Tags: pattern-recognition

there. I came across an encryption problem, as described in the picture. In tought real hard about it but to no avail. There might be a rule governing this kind of encryption.

I wonder how we can solve problems like this one. Is there any general methods that apply? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: This should be asked at [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). Please show your own attempts as well.

Comment: Thank you, Toby, for introducing me to the right community for questions like this one. I'm going there next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is: each word is spelled backwards, and vowels are shifted forward.
So, B is the answer

Comment: B is the answer

Comment: Thank you, aman and Mathew. I think you're quick and right.

Comment: @MichaelMay Accept this answer if you think it answered your question by clicking the small tick-mark on the left side.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I'd tried to do that but the page responded that I should do it after 7 minutes. So, I went away and waited for a while. lol